# Spring Boot 3 authorization with requestMatchers does not authorize access to login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

While migrating a Spring Boot 2.7 application to Spring Boot 3.0.0, I am facing a problem with the login form. This is the configuration before the migration and it worked perfectly:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
.and().httpBasic().disable();

http.authorizeRequests()            
     .antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')")
     .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
```

This would make sure that any request to the application had to be authenticated with the role "USER" while allowing to display the login form anonymously.

With Spring Security 6, I replaced antMatchers with requestsMatchers and there is no way to tell Spring that the login form is authorized without authentication. The only possibility is to allow access to any URL by default. The following is a configuration that works:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests
.requestMatchers("/content/**").hasRole("USER")
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("SUPERADMIN")
.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

But that is not what I really want because this config gives access to any URL by default. What I want is to protect any URL and only give access to the login page, something like this:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests
.requestMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("SUPERADMIN")
.requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
```

But this does not work any more : Spring considers the login page to be protected. Therefore, on login it generates a loop of redirect to the login page.

I have tried different pattenrs : "/login*", "/login**", "/login.html" (the actual login URL), but it does not work unless I give default access to all URL.

Below is the complete SecurityFilterChain that I am currently using.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

// De-activate XSS protection
http.headers().xssProtection().disable();
http.httpBasic().disable();
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/content/**").hasRole("USER")
    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("SUPERADMIN")
    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .successHandler(customLoginSuccessHandler)
    .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandle).loginPage("/login.html")
    .usernameParameter("username")//
    .passwordParameter("password")//
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")//
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())//
    .and().rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())//
    .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600)// 2 weeks
    .alwaysRemember(true).useSecureCookie(true).and().csrf();
            
    http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(true));
            
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: Actually, requestMatchers works for me. But the ResponseStatusException doesn't work.

Comment: Raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33934

Comment: Thank you @Xuan. I don't understand how ResponseStatusException is related to his problem? I must miss something.

Comment: I didn't test your case but just want to tell you that the requestMatchers seems still working fine. However, I found a new serious issue (ResponseStatusException) related to Spring Boot 3. I think maybe your issue is somewhere else of Spring Boot 3, not at requestMatchers.
IMO, we should not switch to Spring Boot 3 yet until it's more stable.

Comment: I have checked the case you opened on GitHub. I think the 403 error comes from the fact that when the code raises the exception, it tries to redirect you to the /error page but then this page is not allowed. It is something different I would say.

Comment: In your case, you need to add `.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()` to make it works.
So, I guess, you also need to permit some specific routes to replace the dirty `/**` here.